# Solr subquery merging issue

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, subquery

I have an issue to search with SOLR in following scenario,

I'd like to get all products within my favorite tag, categories and user. I want all products which created by my favorite user without any filter but products from favorite tag or categories must be filtered with in a selected location. I have tried as follows,

```
http://www.example.com:8983/solr/collection1/select?rows=10&start=0&wt=json&indent=true&sort=event_start_date asc&q=status:1 AND event_start_date:[2015-04-23T21:38:00Z TO *] AND ( tags:5539d77455061a650f96c67e OR category1_id:53d16fb28066a12606bbb5f2 OR category2_id:53d16fb28066a12606bbb5f2&fq={!geofilt d=40.2335}&pt=9.9312328,76.26730409999999&sfield=latlng) OR ( user_id:5465da1dc54d3c2a15000000 )
```

But its not working. Any body help me to find what's wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have a `fq` (filterquery clause) inside your query clause (check parenthesis) which is wrong.

`fq={!geofilt d=40.2335}&pt=9.9312328,76.26730409999999&sfield=latlng`

You can try things like puting the geofilt filter query OUTSIDE your main query with tests so it will be skipped if...

`http://www.example.com:8983/solr/collection1/select?rows=10&start=0&wt=json&indent=true&sort=event_start_date asc&q=status:1 AND 
event_start_date:[2015-04-23T21:38:00Z TO *] AND
(tags:5539d77455061a650f96c67e OR
category1_id:53d16fb28066a12606bbb5f2 OR
category2_id:53d16fb28066a12606bbb5f2) OR
(user_id:5465da1dc54d3c2a15000000)
&fq=user_id:5465da1dc54d3c2a15000000 OR
{!geofilt pt=9.9312328,76.26730409999999 sfield=latlng d=40.2335}`

If user_id is `5465da1dc54d3c2a15000000` then the filterquery is already true so **location part is skipped**.

Comment: Thanks Jerome. But how will it applies location filter for category and tags only?

Comment: It's not really that it applies location filter for category and tags only, it is that it doesn't apply location filter if user_id is 5465da1dc54d3c2a15000000, which in your case is the same.